# What's the difference between And filter and Bool filter in Elastic Search?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

I'm having a trouble understanding the difference between the Bool filter and the And filter in elastic search.

**Context**: say my documents have fields: X, Y, Z.

Each field can have multiple values.

**Goal**:

I want to send a query to elastic search in the following sense: (X=valueX1 OR X=valueX2) AND (Y=valueY1 OR Y=valueY2 OR .. ) AND (Z=valueZ1 OR Z=valueZ2 OR ...).

**Attempt**:

This is how I'm doing that:

```
BoolFilterBuilder mainClaus = FilterBuilders.boolFilter();
FilterBuilder filterBuilder = mainClaus;

BoolFilterBuilder xClaus = FilterBuilders.boolFilter();
BoolFilterBuilder yClaus = FilterBuilders.boolFilter();
BoolFilterBuilder zClaus = FilterBuilders.boolFilter();

mainClaus.must(xClaus);
mainClaus.must(yClaus);
mainClaus.must(zClaus);

//Return a document if it has at least one of those values.
xClaus.should( FilterBuilders.termFilter("X", "valueX1") );
xClaus.should( FilterBuilders.termFilter("X", "valueX2") );
xClaus.should( FilterBuilders.termFilter("X", "valueX3") );

//Return a document if it has at least one of those values.
yClaus.should( FilterBuilders.termFilter("Y", "valueY1") );
yClaus.should( FilterBuilders.termFilter("Y", "valueY2") );
yClaus.should( FilterBuilders.termFilter("Y", "valueY3") );

//Return a document if it has at least one of those values.
zClaus.should( FilterBuilders.termFilter("Z", "valueZ1") );
zClaus.should( FilterBuilders.termFilter("Z", "valueZ2") );
zClaus.should( FilterBuilders.termFilter("Z", "valueZ3") );
```

**Questions**:

- Is my approach correct?
- What's the difference between the Bool filter and the And filter?

Answer (score 5):

The main difference lies in how they are executed. And the keyword here is **bitset**. Simply put, `bool` filters leverage bitsets, while `and` filters do not.

When `bool` filters are used, bitsets are created and then AND/OR'ed together in order to figure out the matching documents.

When `and` filters are used, ES simply scans through the list of documents one by one and includes it or not depending on whether it matches the filter or not.

Needless to say that a `bool` filter is a much faster alternative than a `and` one. Yet, not always. There are situations where you still want to prefer `and` over `bool`: when using geo filters, script filter and numeric range filter, i.e. when those filters are used, ES has to iterate over all documents anyway.

However, all of this only holds for ES pre-2.0, as [starting in 2.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/_query_dsl_changes.html#_literal_or_literal_and_literal_and_literal_now_implemented_via_literal_bool_literal), `and`/`or` filters will be implemented as `bool` and the query DSL will be completely overhauled, so that there won't be any difference anymore between queries and filters.

For more in depth info, you can read the nitty gritty details in this great blog post titled: ["All about ES filter bitsets"](https://www.elastic.co/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets)

So what you're doing is OK, but a more concise alternative would be to simply `must` three `terms` filter, like this:

```
BoolFilterBuilder mainClaus = FilterBuilders.boolFilter();
mainClaus.must(FilterBuilders.termsFilter("X", "valueX1", "valueX2", "valueX3"));
mainClaus.must(FilterBuilders.termsFilter("Y", "valueY1", "valueY2", "valueY3"));
mainClaus.must(FilterBuilders.termsFilter("Z", "valueZ1", "valueZ2", "valueZ3"));
```

Comment: Is my approach correct then to solve what i'm trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your first question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using boolean filters here, you should go for a multi-match query.
Since you are comparning one variable 'X' with three different values, something like the code below would be a better approach.

```
String [] params = {'valueX1','valueX3','valueX3'}

queryBuilder =  QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery('X', params);
```

This queryBuilder can then be added as a part of a bigger 'must' query where all three variable X, Y and Z can be compared.

You can read more about multimatch queries here.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html

Comment: Beware though that the terms he's trying to match are mixed cased (lower-/upppercase), which means he probably wants exact matching without analysis, which multi-match doesn't do. If the mixed case just happens to be coincidental, then multi-match might work fine as well.